# What is ANALYZE/CATALOG for Linux msginit binary message catalog?

Tags: i18n

VMS has an ANALYZE command that examines an item such as an executable image or an object file displaying information about its contents. Is there such a command for examining the output of msginit which is a binary message catalog file? Something equivalent to ANALYZE/CATALOG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`info gettext` might give you some clues. I am not sure what do you really need, but `msgunfmt` looks promising.

Comment: Better than just analyze, it converts back to a source file.